# Example for ShadowOptionsObject

Tags: highcharts

I enabled shadow: true 
Now, I want to customize the shadow by adding custom values for color, offsetX, offsetY, opacity, width 
is there an example somewhere? I am a bit lost, THX!

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.ShadowOptionsObject#toc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find information how to use the shadow available options: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.shadow

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lu89x4ra/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      shadow: {
        color: 'red',
        offsetX: 10,
        offsetY: 10
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: thx - so easy. just adding the member solved it, instead of the mere "true" ...